# What are the asp:DropDownList client side events?

Tags: asp.net, events, drop-down-menu, client-side

I want to know the client side events (like onChange) for an asp:DropDownList.

Comment: What is your exact need?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Are you talking about ASP app? This app produces HTML code so you have all HTML events available, which for the `select` tag (`select` is a HTML tag for dropdown lists) are the following:

- `onchange`
- `onclick`
- `ondblclick`
- `onmousedown`
- `onmouseup`
- `onmouseover`
- `onmousemove`
- `onmouseout`
- `onkeypress`
- `onkeydown`
- `onkeyup`
- `onfocus`
- `onblur`

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Updated my answer.

Comment: `onfocus` and `onblur` are missing as well

Comment: Added those as well to my answer.

Comment: it is worth noting here that you must call your event with parenthesis, unlike regular event calls in a server tag;

server side event: OnSelectedIndexChanged="Event"
client side event: onchange="Event()"

Answer (score 14):

You can assign the [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/onchange) client-side event to a DropDownList control programmatically:

```
DropDownListID.Attributes["onchange"] = "javaScriptFunction();";
```

Give a look to this article:

- [Working with Client-Side Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479302.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Though the question then is, how do you get the client-side id of the SELECT element? Will it be DropDownListID.ClientID or is there a containing DIV that gets added round it?